# Prevent neo4j from starting on boot (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, init

Currently, Neo4j service starts every time I boot into Ubuntu. This is undesired behavior as I am using this as a dev machine and do not always need neo4j running.

Here is the init.d script for it. Do you think I should edit this script to fit my needs? How would I go about doing this? Is there a simpler alternative? I would prefer to avoid modifying this code if at all possible.

```
#! /bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Neo4j Graph Database"
NAME=neo4j
DAEMON=/var/lib/$NAME/bin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="start"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME-service

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --chuid ${NEO_USER} --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
        || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --chuid ${NEO_USER} --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
        $DAEMON_ARGS \
        || return 2
    # Copy the Neo4j PID to the sytem's PID store
    cp /var/lib/${NAME}/data/neo4j-service.pid $PIDFILE
}

do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --chuid ${NEO_USER} --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2

    start-stop-daemon --chuid ${NEO_USER} --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}

# Ensure that the NEO_USER is set to a useful default.
[ -n "${NEO_USER}" ] || NEO_USER=$NAME

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  status)
       status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
       ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
      # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indepently of neo4j you can use [`update-rc.d`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) command to manage init.d based services:

```
update-rc.d -f neo4j-service remove
```

Comment: This simply removes the script, yeah? What if I want to keep the `sudo service neo4j-service (start|stop|reload|restart)` functionality?

Comment: no, this should remove the symlinks for various runlevel directory. The script itself should be kept in /etc/init.d.